# Characterization of primary ideals in a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

On the commutative algebra wiki, a [table of properties](http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Primary_ideal) lists that

> "for a PID, the primary ideals coincide with the powers of prime ideals."

I played around with it, couldn't produce a proof, and have been searching around for a proof, since I'm sure this is a standard fact. I couldn't find a reference online. Can someone please provide a proof, or reference where I can read such a proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can identify an ideal with its generator. Note that $x \in (a)$ if and only if $a\mid x$. Suppose $a=p^n$. If $x \notin (a)$ but $xy \in (a)$, since $p^n \mid xy$ we get $p\mid y$, hence  $p^n\mid y^n$, and  $y^n \in (a)$.

If $a=p^aq^bc$, where $c$ is any element of the ring coprime to the primes $p$ and $q$, $p\ne q$, then let $x=p^a$ and $y=q^bc$. Then $xy\in (a)$ but $x^n$ and $y^n$ are not in $(a)$ for any $n$.

Comment: You wrote $x \in (a)$ if and only if $x \, | \, a$, but you did not seem to follow this afterwards, so I guess it's a typo (you meant $a \, | \, x$).

Comment: It would be nice if you also mentioned that you implicitly used that a PID is also a UFD. But nice proof anyway.  +1

Comment: Thanks Brett. Also, when you write $a=p^aq^bc$, I assume the $a$s are different things, yes?

Comment: Yeah, bad choice of notation there.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva: what property of UFD is being used here? Thanks

Comment: @Quand Dao : He used only the definition of a PID to have a complete characterization of the ideals of A (i.e. those with a single generator) and the definition of a UFD to factor those generators. He then shows that powers of prime ideals are primary and that those which are not powers of prime ideals are not primary.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I do not understand why p divides y? Is there some property of UFD being used here?

Comment: Just write x and y as a power of $p$ times an element coprime to $p$ and use the assumptions

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: So $xy = \lambda p^n$, and $x$ will be the power of $p$ times an unit, and since $x$ is not in $(a)$, the power of $p$ in $x$ will be less than $n$, therefore $p$ divides $y$?

Comment: @Quang Dao : You are not working in a local PID, only a PID. The element $x$ will be divisible by a certain power of $p$ but the exponent will be less than $n$. You should only be careful with the definitions and assumptions in the question!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Peel off prime factors of an element $\ne 0$ in $\rm\:\! J = (j)\:$ till only one prime $\rm\:q\:$ remains, via

$$\rm\ j\ |\ p^n\: x,\ \ j\nmid p^n\ \Rightarrow\ \ j\ |\ x^k \ \Rightarrow\ \cdots\ \Rightarrow\ \ j\ |\ q^m,\quad p,\:q\ \ prime$$

More generally, a similar proof shows that the radical of a primary ideal is prime.

Comment: I am not about what comes after "via", could you explain a bit further?

Comment: @Pedro Continue peeling prime powers $\ j\mid x^k = q^i y,\ j\nmid q^i\Rightarrow\, j\mid y^{k'},\,\ldots$

Comment: You mean use a PID is noetherian? I am not sure about what the details of the proof would be. I would appreciate if you could include a full proof. I am interested in the direct approach.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I don't know what proof you have in mind.

Comment: Details about the proof in your post. It'd be nice if you could give a usual worded proof.

Comment: @Pedro The hinted proof shows, by induction on $\,n =$ #prime factors of $\ a = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n},\ p_i$ prime,  that primary $\,j\mid a\,\Rightarrow\, j\mid p_i^k,\,$ for some prime $\,p_i\mid a.\,$ Choosing $\,a = j\,$ implies that $\,j\mid p_i^k.\ \ $